# Coordinates of an n-sphere

Tags: spherical-coordinates

*I'm a little embarrassed to ask this question because it should be easy but it's stumped me for over a week now. The answer will determine how I write some code, so it matters.*

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates) the coordinates of an n-sphere in $n$ coordinates is given as

\begin{align}
x_1 &= r \cos(\phi_1) \\
x_2 &= r \sin(\phi_1) \cos(\phi_2) \\
x_3 &= r \sin(\phi_1) \sin(\phi_2) \cos(\phi_3) \\
    &\vdots\\
x_{n-1} &= r \sin(\phi_1) \cdots \sin(\phi_{n-2}) \cos(\phi_{n-1}) \\
x_n &= r \sin(\phi_1) \cdots \sin(\phi_{n-2}) \sin(\phi_{n-1}) \,.
\end{align}

By this formula, the coordinates of an n-sphere in 4 coordinates *should* be

\begin{align}
x_1 &= r \cos(\phi_1) \\
x_2 &= r \sin(\phi_1) \cos(\phi_2) \\
x_3 &= r \sin(\phi_1) \sin(\phi_2) \cos(\phi_3) \\
x_4 &= r \sin(\phi_1) \sin(\phi_2) \sin(\phi_3)
\end{align}

Whereas [mathworld.wolfram.com](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hypersphere.html) gives coordinates as (allowing for a change of notation and ordering)

\begin{align}
x_1 &= r \cos(\phi_1) \\
x_2 &= r \sin(\phi_1) \cos(\phi_2) \\
x_3 &= r \sin(\phi_1) \sin(\phi_2) \sin(\phi_3) \\
x_4 &= r \sin(\phi_1) \sin(\phi_2) \cos(\phi_3)
\end{align}

Which is correct? Note that $x_3$ and $x_4$ are swapped in my version and wolfram's.

Comment: They're both perfectly good parameterizations of the sphere, they just happen to be distinct ones. In fact, this particular equivalence corresponds to the fact that the unit $4$-sphere is symmetric about the plane $x_3 = x_4$.

Comment: You already have this issue for a circle: you could parameterize a circle as $x =r \cos \theta, y = r \sin \theta$ or as $x = r \sin \theta, y = r \cos \theta$. Which is "correct"? They're both parameterizations, just different ones.